# why "this" keyword in arrow function represents the object rather than global object(window)

Tags: javascript, this, es6-class

I am learning the behavior of `this` keyword in **ES6 class** , before I have learnt that `this` keyword in object functions, represent the following :

- In **regular function**, `this` represents the the **current object**.
- In **arrow function**, `this` represent the **global object(window)**.

So, when I worked with ES6 class I see that Class behave as `Object` when it is complied into JavaScript ,I see this behavior in console by putting `this` in a class method and `this` was representing the current class as `Object` as well as its prototype was `Object`.

For conceptual understanding, I make one **Arrow function** `foo()` and one **Regular function** `bar()` in a class **AppComponent** and print `this` keyword  as follow:

[image]

I was expecting that `this` in **foo()**  would represent *global object(window)* , because it is inside **Arrow function** in the `Object` and ,on the other side,in the **bar()** `this` represent the current object due to **Regular function** inside `object` which is **AppComponent**, but the output was:

[image]

**bar()** output is expected.

**foo()** output is unexpected.

So, my question is that why `this` represent the current **Object** Appcomnent rather than global object(window), because it is inside the `arrow function` in the **object** .

*Please correct me if my concept is not correct in the question ,if it is correct then why I see the unexpected output. I would very thankful to you for your contribution.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Please don't post your code as images; **code is text**. In the future, please include your code as properly formatted text.

Comment: *In arrow function, this represent the global object(window).* — No, it doesn't. `this` is lexical (inherited from the environment where the function is defined). It's only `window` if the value of `this` is `window` when it is defined … and you're asking about public class fields, which are different.

Comment: *"In arrow function, this represent the global object(window)"* That's incorrect. `this` inside an arrow function is whatever `this` is outside it, which may be the global object, or may be something else. In your case, `this` in your `foo` is a reference to the object being constructed, exactly as though you'd written `this.foo = () => { /*...*? };` in the constructor, because `this` within a `class` construct's class fields initializer is a reference to the object being constructed. That's how class fields are defined.

Comment: it means, inside a class "this" will always represent the class as object in arrow or regular function?

Comment: @FZs - That's not correct, see [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72292221/why-this-keyword-in-arrow-function-represents-the-object-rather-than-global-ob?noredirect=1#comment127717677_72292221). Functions aren't the only way the value of `this` is set (just the primary way, outside of modules where it's set to `undefined`).

Comment: @Ubaid - Not always, but it will within an initializer of an instance field like your `foo`. Inside a method, it'll be whatever `this` is in the method call, which depends on how the method was called. Inside an initializer on a `static` class field, it'll be a reference to the class constructor function.

Comment: it means the scope of this inside a class would change depending upon where and how we are using it ?

Comment: @Ubaid - No. First off, `this` isn't scope. But the *value* of `this` doesn't depend on where the class is defined, it depends on where *within* the class `this` is used. Again, in an instance field initializer, it'll be the instance being created (as though the code were in the constructor). In a static field initializer, it'll be the class constructor function. In a method, it'll be whatever it is in that method, which depends on how the method is called. None of that varies depending on where the class is defined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ,thank you for correcting me ,i should say value instead of scope and thanks for your explanation